# Relation between realizability and conservativity of a functor

Tags: category-theory

I was wondering if there is some relation between this two notions, in general or in some particular context.
I call a functor $F:A\rightarrow B$ realizable if $\forall y\in Ob(B)$ we can find an element $x\in A$ such that $F(x)=y$. For instance, if I am not wrong, the fundemantal group is such a functor.
On the other hand a functor is conservative it it reflects isomorphisms, hence we can say that $f\in Hom(A)$ isomorphism $\Leftrightarrow$  $F(f)$ isomorphism. For instance the functor which to any affine variety assigns its coordinate ring  algebra  $\mathcal{O}(X)$, is conservative.

In some sense I would intuitively expect that the two notions  should not happen together easily since their combination is quite strong.(Much as in the same way as compactness and Hausdorfness are "inversely" related feature for a topological space).  In the example we know that sadly the fundamental group is in general not conservative and that $\mathcal{O}(\cdot)$ is realizable only if we restrict to finetely generated algbras with non nihilpotent elements. 
(Much as in the same way as compactness and Hausdorfness are "inversely" related feature for a topological space). 
Thanks for any information.

Comment: Note that what you call "conservative" is not what (I think) most people call conservative. The general definition is that a functor is conservative if for every morphism $f:x\to y$ in $A$, $F(f)$ is an isomorphism iff $f$ is an isomorphism. For example, any functor between discrete categories is conservative in that sense but not necessarily in yours.

Comment: You are right, I will correct it

Comment: What you call realizability is what's usually called essentially surjectivity, though note that one only asks for an isomorphism $F(x) \simeq y$.